# Android Chrome Cast button

Tags: android, google-chrome, button, google-cast, chromecast

I'm just developing a chrome cast app and got stuck on one basic step. I'm following some examples from the Internet concerning the GUI for Chrome Cast. The button that is supposed to launch the cast (first choose a device) is normally located in the action bar. This is how it's added:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    mCastManager.addMediaRouterButton(menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);

    return true;
}
```

and XML for R.id.media_route_menu_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
        android:title="@string/media_route_menu_title"
        app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

as you can see in the 2nd part:

```
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
```

will start the Chrome Cast devices choice. I need to move the menu element out of action bar and make a Button which does the same. The problem is I cannot do something like

```
<Button
...
            app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
/>
```

it won't work since actionProviderClass is prepared to work with menu items. I'd be thankful for any ideas how to solve that problem using a button.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out this [sample](https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android) on our GitHub repository, we show three different ways to do that. If you still have questions after going through them, come back and we'll see what we can do to help.

Comment: Hi Ali, your sample MediaRouterButtonActivity works great when using FragmentActivity but when using MediaRouter.Callback in a fragment the onRouteAdded method is almost never triggered. Any idea how this can be used in a fragment instead so I can set the mediaRouteButton to visible when entering the fragment?

Comment: FragmentActivity is a requirement enforced by MediaRoute support library. What type of activity holds your fragment?

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 4):

You can use the MediaRouteButton like so:

```
XML
<android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
 android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Java

```
MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton = MediaRouteButton) findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
mediaRouteButton.setRouteSelector(your_selector);
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I was using the regular button type in my XML file. After changing the button type to MediaRouteButton it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete Silva's answer this is what you need in your activity if you are using Tollbar:

```
MediaRouteButton mediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.mediaRouteMenuItem);
// mediaRouteButton.setRouteSelector(MediaRouteSelector.EMPTY);
CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(this, mediaRouteButton);
```